# Start a program in the background and stop the script from loading further

Tags: php

I want to start a php script in the background.What i am doing is running this code

```
<?php
while(true){
$commandString = 'start /b C:\xampp\php\php.exe  "C:\xampp\htdocs\caliban\blobs.php"'; 
popen($commandString, 'r'); 
sleep(5);
}
?>
```

in the web browser but the page won't stop loading.How can i execute this code and stop the web browser from loading further without stopping the task being done in the background?.

blobs.php

```
<?php

//pdo connect function
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//third function
$firstname = rand(4,4);
$lastname = rand(4,4);
$city = rand(4,4);
$continent = rand(4,4);
$profile = rand(4,4);
$image = rand(4,4);
$sql = "INSERT INTO mymodels ".
       "(firstname,lastname,city,continent,image,profile) ".
       "VALUES ".
       "('$firstname','$lastname','$city','$continent','$image','$profile')";
mysql_select_db('caliban');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}



?>
```

Sql

```
create table mymodels(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   firstname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   lastname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   city VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   continent VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   image BLOB,
   profile VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function close_connection(){
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Connection: close");
    ignore_user_abort(); // optional
    ob_start();
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Then

```
<?php
    close_connection();
    while(true){
        $commandString = 'start /b C:\xampp\php\php.exe  "C:\xampp\htdocs\caliban\blobs.php"'; 
        popen($commandString, 'r'); 
        sleep(5);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 6 times. There's no reason it should stop "working". Try adding this line after the flushes `fastcgi_finish_request();`

Comment: Updated the question to include the script i am executing.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this

```
<?php
function close_connection(){
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Connection: close");
    ignore_user_abort(); // optional
    ob_start();
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}
close_connection();
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\xampp\htdocs\caliban\blobs.bat');

?>
```

worked.This is my blobs.bat

> php c:\xampp\htdocs\caliban\blobs.php

To completely hide the command line

i created this in.vbs file and put this in

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

My php file looks like

```
<?php
function close_connection(){
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Connection: close");
    ignore_user_abort(); // optional
    ob_start();
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}
close_connection();
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\xampp\htdocs\caliban\in.vbs C:\xampp\htdocs\caliban\blobs.bat');

?>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Reference

https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file